# Calculated field turns invalid in Data Source Preview

Tags: tableau-api

I am having a Access DB file with several tables.
In order to create a calculated field with a regex matching in there, I created a Tableau workbook with an extract of the data.

What I do is trying to match the Top Level Domain out of [Web Location] which contains valid URLs and save it in the field TopLvlDomain:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([Web Location],'(?:\.([a-z]{2,6})(?:\/|$))' )
```

That works well and gives me what I want:

[image]

If I go to the Preview Data Source tab in Tableau however, it tells me that the field calculation is invalid:

[image]

Why is that and how do I resolve it?

The reason why it matters is that I have another table that has country codes in it and I would like to join it to get the full country name. I know that it is not totally reliable (think com, org, etc. domains) but for the purpose it is accurately enoough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your calculation is correct and this will work in Excel (or any other data source that supports Tableau's REGEX). However, Access does not support these Tableau REGEX functions.

[See docs](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/en-us/help.html#functions_functions_additional.html):

> REGEXP_EXTRACT(string, pattern) Returns the portion of the string that
>   matches the regular expression pattern. This function is available for
>   **Text File, Hadoop Hive, Google BigQuery, PostgreSQL, Tableau Data
>   Extract, Microsoft Excel, Salesforce, and Oracle data sources.**

One option, which seems to be what you did, is to create an extract of the Access DB and then use that to run the REGEX on. You can refresh the extract to keep it up to date with the data in your Access DB.

Comment: Ok it seems that I saved the extract but then worked in the workbook with the live connection. Which is weird because it says extract on the radio button on the top right. Which kind of changes my problem then and I might have to change the question.

Comment: What I did now is creating the RegEx calculation in the extract, then I open the original database and blend the country table with the calculated field. Seems overly complicated but if that's the way to go...